# Access is denied Exception when using Respond.js

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to support media query on IE old versions, I download [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) library, I try to 
run the test example they provide but this error occur in IE old versions

```
Message: Access is denied.

Line: 287
Char: 4
Code: 0
```

BTW, I am not using the minized version!

Answer (score 3):

Even i had the issue when i was trying to open "test.html" directly from folder:

```
file:///C:/Respond-master/test/test.html
```

Got fixed when i placed the file in local server and opened it from browser:

```
http://localhost/Respond-master/test/test.html
```